# JAX-WS client: maintain session/cookies across multiple services

Tags: java, cookies, jax-ws, session-cookies, jax-ws-customization

I'm using Netbeans to automatically create webservice clients based off WSDL files. This works well, except the webservices I'm using require that I pass in a custom cookie in the HTTP header to every webservice in order to prove my identity.

I use one webservice named `Utility` to get my authorization. This sets a cookie which needs to be provided in all subsequent calls to any webservice.

This can be accomplished by setting `javax.xml.ws.session.maintain` to `true` on the BindingProvider of the port for the webservice. This works great for subsequent calls to the methods in the `Utility` webservice.
The problem is that this only maintains the session/cookie for that single webservice. I need it across others as well.

I need the cookie passed in to a *separate* webservice named `History`  How can I accomplish this?  Is it feasible to have a super Service class which both Utility and History could extend and share the same session state with?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've found a solution.

You can get response headers using this after you've made the call:

```
((BindingProvider)port).getResponseContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);
```

Find the `Set-Cookie` header and store its value.

Then before your next request (in any webservice) you can set the Cookie header:

```
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(
            MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,
                Collections.singletonMap("Cookie", Collections.singletonList(cookieValue)
            )
        );
```

Comment: Perhaps you have to add that extracting the Cookie this way is only possible directly after the first call - since only there "Set-Cookie" is set. But nontheless... thank you very much. This saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

Just commenting because solution above didn't work for me.  I got UnsupportedOperationException.  I believe issue was caused because singletonMap doesn't allow changes.  xml headers were also needed, so I set those first.

```
Map<String, List<String>> headers= CastUtils.cast((Map)port.getRequestContext().get("javax.xml.ws.http.request.headers"));
if (headers == null) {
    headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    port.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.http.request.headers", headers);
}

headers.put("Cookie", Collections.singletonList(cookieValue));
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```

Comment: Yes, SingletonMaps are immutable -- i used it merely as a convenience

Comment: You should review code to get it more compact, knowing MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS == "javax.xml.ws.http.request.headers"

Comment: His version is actually one char shorter even including quotes, but I know what you mean. Using a constant is certainly safer. :)