# java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList to Collections.singletonList

Tags: java, collections, type-conversion

How to I convert a `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList` to a `Collections.singletonList`?
In a attempt to store session between two services, i found this, but I cant figure out the step in between.
First get the cookie info that i need to set:

```
Map<String, Collections> headerInfo = (Map<String, Collections>)
 ((BindingProvider) port).getResponseContext()
                         .get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);
```

Now I can get the cookie info i need; 
If I do a

```
System.out.println(headerInfo.get("Set-Cookie"));
```

I get something like this

```
Set-Cookie=[PHPSESSID=rpsnc2g7o4ltbr6l9qus177p14; path=/];
```

Now I just need to do this:

```
((BindingProvider) port2).getRequestContext()
   .put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, 
      Collections.singletonMap("Cookie", Collections.singletonList(cookieValue)));
```

But I can not figure out how to get from
`headerInfo.get("Set-Cookie")` to: `cookieValue`

This is the question I found the first part of my problems solution in Q: 
[JAX-WS client: maintain session/cookies across multiple services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699114/jax-ws-client-maintain-session-cookies-across-multiple-services) 
(It might explain my problem a bit too)

Comment: Why do you need to do the conversion at all, instead of just keeping the original list?

Comment: If i attemt using the original list:

((BindingProvider)customer).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,Collections.singletonMap("Cookie", headerInfo.get("Set-Cookie")));


This Exception is thrown:

java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList cannot be cast to java.util.Collections

Comment: Update:
You are right, I did not need the conversion, just the right typecast. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to use the original list by casting to the correct class/interface:

```
List<String>
```

instead of:

```
Collections
```

worked.

```
Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>)((BindingProvider) authPort).getResponseContext().get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);
List<String> setCookie = (List<String>) headers.get("Set-Cookie");
((BindingProvider) servicePort).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS,Collections.singletonMap("Cookie", setCookie ));
```