# Getting and setting Cookies and Session in Webservice

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I had googled for this but havent got any conclusive answers

Is it possible to retrieve and set a cookie in the reponse for JAX-WS webservice ?

How can we maintain sessions in web service ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting and setting Cookies and Session in Webservice is Supported in JAX-WS. Follow the below link which will help you to enable this on server and Client side.

[Programming Stateful JAX-WS Web Services Using HTTP Session](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13734/stateful.htm)

You may also have look at this answer [JAX-WS client: maintain session/cookies across multiple services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699114/jax-ws-client-maintain-session-cookies-across-multiple-services)