# open a page html in a web service in java in SSO

Tags: html, web-services, anonymous

I would like open a html page in a web service, i succedded to do that but i need to take all the rights to do this to anonymous... not good !!

So i try to take the login and password in url and it doesn't work !

```
public static String genererHtml(String docid, String cheminBase, String nomVue, String nomServeurNotes, LogWSDTO logDTO) throws ExceptionWS {

        String str2 = null;
        try 
        {
            StringBuffer sb ;           
            InputStream streamIn = null  ;
            InputStreamReader str ;
            BufferedReader binIn ;
            URL docURL ;

            String URL_FIN = "?OpenDocument";               

            String notesURL = "http://" + "nomServeur/names.nsf?login&username=login&password=password&redirectto=http://nomServeur"  + SEPARATEUR + cheminBase + SEPARATEUR + nomVue + SEPARATEUR + docid + URL_FIN;   

            docURL = new URL(notesURL);

            streamIn = docURL.openStream(); 

            str = new InputStreamReader(streamIn);

            binIn = new BufferedReader(str);
            String lineNext;
            sb = new StringBuffer();            
            while ((lineNext = binIn.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append(lineNext);
            }
            str2 =  new String(sb.toString().getBytes(),"UTF-8");


            streamIn.close();
            str.close();
            binIn.close();

            sb = null;  

        } catch
```

i can't open the line docurl.openStream() ?
Anyone have an idea ?

I have

```
"java.io.ioexception server returned http response code 401 for url"
```

I works with SSO and kerberos, spenego

Please ?!!

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found
i use a cookie to do that

see :
http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=5

and see :
[JAX-WS client: maintain session/cookies across multiple services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699114/jax-ws-client-maintain-session-cookies-across-multiple-services)