# Secure EJB3.1-Webservice (in JBoss Wildfly 8.2)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, ejb

I have a nearly finished web project with EJB3.1 deployed as WAR in Wildfly 8.2. It´s secured by a self-written JAAS-realm with form authentication (auth-method FORM).

Now I want to add a EJB-Webservice which is basically defined as

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class ProductImportWebservice {
    @Resource 
    WebServiceContext wsContext;

    [...]

    @WebMethod
    public Product createOrFind(String name) {
       [...]
    }
}
```

The webservice works as expected but now I have the problem that I want to protect access to the Webservice by username/password.
So I annotated the webservice or the @WebMethod with

```
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
```

which is a valid role in the JAAS-authentication. 
Effect: The SOAP-client gets the answere "reqeust not allowed / not authenticated" - but gets no authentication-request and attempts with BASIC-authentication are ignored.
If I add the URL of the webservice to the security-constraint in the web.xml I get an authentication request... but the problem now is that it´s the form based authentication - as a user with a browser would expect it. This is unusable for a "normal" SOAP-client :-(

The concrete question now is: Is there a way to have both - BASIC authentication for the webservice *and* FORM-based authentication for the rest of the application?

The only other way I would see is to split the WAR package up to an EAR-package and deploy the webservice in a different web-context.

Answer (score 1):

> The concrete question now is: Is there a way to have both - BASIC
>   authentication for the webservice and FORM-based authentication for
>   the rest of the application?

You can't use both `FORM` and `BASIC` authentication for the same web application.

If you need to do this, create two separate applications, with a shared codebase.

Reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier002.htm#JEETT01227

> The auth-method subelement configures the authentication mechanism for
>   the web application. The element content must be either NONE, BASIC,
>   DIGEST, FORM, or CLIENT-CERT.

Comment: Not the answere I hoped for but I think you´re right.
I think I´ll go another way: add the webmethod-parameters with user-credentials und check them on my own :-(

Comment: Just wanted to add: In the end I extended my Webservice with a funktion "login" which delegates the login-process to HttpRequest.login - wich basically calls the JAAS-check.... in the protected methods I check the role-membership by checking wsContext.isUserInRole(...) and the WS-Client simply maintains sessions as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699114/jax-ws-client-maintain-session-cookies-across-multiple-services
It works like a charme and was much less work than splitting up the project.

Comment: @cljk You could also try your luck with JASPIC, which is standard and allows you to stack multiple authenticators (`ServerAuthModule`s) as you please. I doubt it will be trivial to set up for use with both Servlet and JAX-WS though.